# Distribution of limit of random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let $\xi_n$ be normally distributed random variables. I need to proove that if $\xi_n\to\xi$ is convergence in distribution then $\xi$ has also normal distribution (including the case where $\xi = const$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest proof is the one using characteristic functions. We have $Ee^{it\xi}=\lim Ee^{it\xi_n}=\lim e^{i\mu_nt} e^{-t^{2}\sigma_n^{2} /2}$ $\cdots$ (1). This implies that $|Ee^{it\xi}|=\lim  e^{-t^{2}\sigma_n^{2} /2}$. We can conclude from this (by taking logarithm) that $\sigma_n$ converges. Now going back  to (1) we conclude that $e^{i\mu_nt}$ has a limit for every $t$. An elementary argument in complex analysis shows that $\mu_n$ must convege. If $\mu =\lim \mu_n$ and $\sigma =\lim \sigma_n$ then we get $Ee^{it\xi}= e^{imt} e^{-t^{2}\sigma^{2} /2}$, so $\xi$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$.